# Scss: Multiple BEM states class

Tags: sass, bem

I'm using Scss for my current project with BEM state conventions.

What i need:

**CSS**

```
.name {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.name--is-focus {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.name--is-active {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.name--is-focus.name--is-active {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

**SCSS**

```
.name {
    font-size: 10px;

    &--is-focus {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    &--is-active {
        font-size: 14px;
        &.name--is-focus {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    }

}
```

The code works great.
However, is this the right way for situation like this?
I think there should be a more elegant way to do instead of this.

```
&--is-active {
    font-size: 14px;
    &.name--is-focus {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, as such. That said, is the SCSS really benefiting you in this case? Is the SCSS more readable and maintainable than the CSS? Personally, I'd say the CSS is better.